# Difference between !! vs direct check on value

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

What will be difference when we check a value with !! or without it.

Example:-

a) if(!!Value) { do this }  => I know this condition will return a boolean

b) if(Value) { do this }  ==> This will check if value has anything inside it

But what will be difference in their usage? If not above case, in what case they both will make a difference ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929 I'm pretty sure the `!!` is completely pointless, since `if` will already check to see if it's truthy/falsey

Comment: There is no difference. Both will be evaluated the same way. `if (!!Value)` makes it slightly more clear that `Value` is not a boolean to begin with, so it might be useful for letting people who work on that code what to expect but ultimately, it doesn't matter, both are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no difference** using `if(value)` or `if(!!value)` in JavaScript or in TypeScript.

`!!` will coerce any following value to Boolean type.

However, an expression inside a `if` will be coerced to Boolean by JavaScript / TypeScript anyway.

In JavaScript the values that will be coerced to `false` ("*falsy* values") are `false`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`.

Any other is *truthy* (including empty arrays and objects), i.e. will be coerced to `true`.